# Select non whitespace in each lines which does not contain @ symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to take all lines except which contains `@` symbol

This is the regex for it `^[^@]*$/gm`

Now how do i select only words in it as `\S\S*`?

Finally i want to combine these two regex `^[^@]*$/gm` and `\S\S*`

Sample [here](https://regex101.com/r/pL8tX0/1)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: it would be great if you provided a sample text and how the output should look.

Comment: i am using Javascript, sample here https://regex101.com/r/pL8tX0/1

Comment: You cannot combine your regexps in JS the way you need. Use a 2-step approach.

Comment: What about using \S instead of * before $, it is not working.

Comment: Why have you posted [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064951/why-in-regex-shoul-be-only-dot-after-negative-lookahead#34064980)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make it a two-step process: First filter all lines by `/^[^@]*$/`, afterwards get all matches for `/\S+/` from that line. You can't have an arbitrary number of matches from a single regex (e.g. all »words« individually). Unless you want all words separated by whitespace in a single match, such as `/\S+(\s+\S+)*/`, but even then you'd essentially just get the whole line in a single match, so there's little point to it.

Comment: Thank you, if i use \p{L}+ instead of \S\S* then how do i select only 'words' in these lines

Comment: May be i should use negative lookahead?

Comment: @eminach: I removed that part of the answer because it's irrelevant for JavaScript. JavaScript regexes don't know Unicode at all, so your best bets are horrible here either way. `\p{L}` is a character class that contains every Unicode character considered a »letter«, so for matching *words* it's much nicer than »non-whitespace« (which also includes punctuation, digits, etc.). But that all depends a bit on your corpus of text where you need matches. In your case I guess `\S` is fine.

Comment: then how do i except these lines?