# Why in RegEx should be only dot after negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

In my case must select each word lines which does not contain symbol `@`

This `^((?!@).)*$` expressions selects all line with whitespaces too,

I was wondering why it couldn't be put `\S` instead of `.`

Comment: It is the same, i cant combine two task in one regex, i need word by word without whitespaces

Comment: What is your goal? I believe you do not need a tempered greedy token if your task is to match any non-whitespace sequence that has no `@` in it. Just use [`(?<!\S)(?!\S*@)\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/nG4zK6/1).

Comment: Oh i need in javascript ?< does not work with javascript

Comment: I have commented your original question: *You cannot combine your regexps in JS the way you need. Use a 2-step approach.* Nothing will change if you re-post the question again, it is JavaScript.

Comment: This question was my, it is not duplicate..

Comment: You ask for the same thing, if not, please clarify and I  or someone else will relieve the close. *I was wondering why it couldn't be put \S instead of .* qualifies for yet another dupe.

Comment: I asked, why we should put dot after negative lookahead?

Comment: It depends on what you are after. You need to clarify what you need to match/find and supply examples of what you need to match and what you do not want to match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helps me